# Using 32-bit TTS voices on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, tts

I am having problems using a 32-bit voice on a 64-bit system (windows 7). I tried accessing and setting my installed 32-bit voices via
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Speech\SpeechUX\sapi.cpl`, but whenever I open my Word application (Microsoft Word, Excel) the TTS setting reverts back to the default Microsoft Anna.

I heard I could do this by editing my registry files, but I haven't been able to accomplish that. Can anyone help me with a step to step process? I am not tech savvy, so if you could be as detailed as possible, please do.

Update:

In my registry, by merging the strings at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens`
with
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\`,
I have successfully got the installed 32-bits voices to show at the control panel TTS settings.

However, the voice doesn't have audio as I get a "This voice cannot be played" error when I try to preview it via the same settings page.
Nonetheless, when I access the TTS settings using this direct link
`C:\Windows\sysWOW64\speech\SpeechUX\SAPI.cpl`,
the 32-bit voice plays in the preview, but once my Word (64-bit) application opens, it reverts to Microsoft Anna.

Comment: There is a very long thread [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c7409091-087e-48f2-8178-bcd918799054/add-tts-voice-to-windows-7-and-set-as-default?forum=w7itproinstall) about the problem, with successively complicated answers. It might be helpful, but too long for me to try.

Comment: Thanks for your response harrymc. 
I actually used the procedure detailed in the link you posted. That was how I was eventually able to have the 32bit voice display in the default control panel TTS settings. The problem now is that it displays, but it's unable to play or usable on my computer.